# nothing gets downloaded with apt-get, gets unmet dependencies each time, even with java

Tags: apt, 16.04, libreoffice

I used apt-get for almost installing every application i needed, but after installing a new Ubuntu version (16.04) I am no longer able to use that command. every time I use it it tells the packages I am installing has unmet dependencies, it happened when I tried to install Java, LibreOffice, flash and even aptitude.

As an example this is the output that I get when I try to install LibreOffice

```
sudo apt-get install libreoffice
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libreoffice : Depends: libreoffice-base but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libreoffice-calc but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libreoffice-core (= 1:5.1.4-0ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libreoffice-draw but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libreoffice-impress but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libreoffice-math but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libreoffice-report-builder-bin but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libreoffice-writer but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libreoffice-avmedia-backend-gstreamer but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: fonts-dejavu but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: python3-uno (>= 4.4.0~beta2) but it is not going to be installed
               Recommends: libreoffice-gnome but it is not going to be installed or
                           libreoffice-kde but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

---

The output of "dir /etc/apt/sources.list.d"

```
libreoffice-ubuntu-libreoffice-4-4-xenial.list
openjdk-r-ubuntu-ppa-xenial.list
openjdk-r-ubuntu-ppa-xenial.list.save
webupd8team-ubuntu-java-xenial.list
webupd8team-ubuntu-java-xenial.list.save
```

---

the output of cat /etc/apt/sources.list

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 16.04 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20160420.1)]/ xenial main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial restricted multiverse
# deb-src http://ae.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates restricted multiverse
# deb-src http://ae.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in
## universe WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu security
## team.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial universe
# deb-src http://ae.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates universe
# deb-src http://ae.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
# deb-src http://ae.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial multiverse
# deb-src http://ae.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://ae.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security restricted multiverse
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security universe
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security universe
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security multiverse
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-security main multiverse
deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian wheezy-backports main
deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian jessie-backports main
```

---

the output of sudo apt-get update

```
Hit:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Ign:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/libreoffice/libreoffice-4-4/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease                
Ign:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-security InRelease               
Hit:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/openjdk-r/ppa/ubuntu xenial InRelease           
Hit:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease              
Hit:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu xenial InRelease        
Ign:8 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-security Release                 
Hit:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease               
Ign:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/libreoffice/libreoffice-4-4/ubuntu xenial Release
Ign:11 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-security/main amd64 Packages.diff/Index
Ign:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/libreoffice/libreoffice-4-4/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
Ign:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/libreoffice/libreoffice-4-4/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
Ign:14 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-security/main i386 Packages.diff/Index
Ign:15 http://ppa.launchpad.net/libreoffice/libreoffice-4-4/ubuntu xenial/main all Packages
Ign:16 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-security/main all Packages
Ign:17 http://ppa.launchpad.net/libreoffice/libreoffice-4-4/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en_US
Ign:18 http://ppa.launchpad.net/libreoffice/libreoffice-4-4/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en
Ign:19 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-security/main Translation-en_US
Ign:20 http://ppa.launchpad.net/libreoffice/libreoffice-4-4/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:21 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-security/main Translation-en
Ign:22 http://ppa.launchpad.net/libreoffice/libreoffice-4-4/ubuntu xenial/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/libreoffice/libreoffice-4-4/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
Ign:23 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-security/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/libreoffice/libreoffice-4-4/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
Ign:24 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-security/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:15 http://ppa.launchpad.net/libreoffice/libreoffice-4-4/ubuntu xenial/main all Packages
Ign:25 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-security/multiverse amd64 Packages.diff/Index
Ign:17 http://ppa.launchpad.net/libreoffice/libreoffice-4-4/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en_US
Ign:18 http://ppa.launchpad.net/libreoffice/libreoffice-4-4/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en
Ign:26 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-security/multiverse i386 Packages.diff/Index
Ign:20 http://ppa.launchpad.net/libreoffice/libreoffice-4-4/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:27 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-security/multiverse all Packages
Ign:22 http://ppa.launchpad.net/libreoffice/libreoffice-4-4/ubuntu xenial/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/libreoffice/libreoffice-4-4/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
Ign:28 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-security/multiverse Translation-en_US
Ign:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/libreoffice/libreoffice-4-4/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
Ign:29 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-security/multiverse Translation-en
Ign:15 http://ppa.launchpad.net/libreoffice/libreoffice-4-4/ubuntu xenial/main all Packages
Ign:30 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-security/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:17 http://ppa.launchpad.net/libreoffice/libreoffice-4-4/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en_US
Ign:31 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-security/multiverse DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:18 http://ppa.launchpad.net/libreoffice/libreoffice-4-4/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en
Ign:32 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-security/main amd64 Packages
Ign:20 http://ppa.launchpad.net/libreoffice/libreoffice-4-4/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:22 http://ppa.launchpad.net/libreoffice/libreoffice-4-4/ubuntu xenial/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:33 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-security/main i386 Packages
Ign:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/libreoffice/libreoffice-4-4/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
Ign:16 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-security/main all Packages
Ign:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/libreoffice/libreoffice-4-4/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
Ign:15 http://ppa.launchpad.net/libreoffice/libreoffice-4-4/ubuntu xenial/main all Packages
Ign:19 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-security/main Translation-en_US
Ign:17 http://ppa.launchpad.net/libreoffice/libreoffice-4-4/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en_US
Ign:21 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-security/main Translation-en
Ign:18 http://ppa.launchpad.net/libreoffice/libreoffice-4-4/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en
Ign:20 http://ppa.launchpad.net/libreoffice/libreoffice-4-4/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:23 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-security/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:22 http://ppa.launchpad.net/libreoffice/libreoffice-4-4/ubuntu xenial/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/libreoffice/libreoffice-4-4/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
Ign:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/libreoffice/libreoffice-4-4/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
Ign:24 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-security/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:15 http://ppa.launchpad.net/libreoffice/libreoffice-4-4/ubuntu xenial/main all Packages
Ign:34 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-security/multiverse amd64 Packages
Ign:17 http://ppa.launchpad.net/libreoffice/libreoffice-4-4/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en_US
Ign:18 http://ppa.launchpad.net/libreoffice/libreoffice-4-4/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en
Ign:35 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-security/multiverse i386 Packages
Get:36 http://ftp.debian.org/debian wheezy-backports InRelease [163 kB]
Ign:20 http://ppa.launchpad.net/libreoffice/libreoffice-4-4/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:27 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-security/multiverse all Packages
Ign:22 http://ppa.launchpad.net/libreoffice/libreoffice-4-4/ubuntu xenial/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Err:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/libreoffice/libreoffice-4-4/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found
Ign:28 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-security/multiverse Translation-en_US
Err:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/libreoffice/libreoffice-4-4/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
  404  Not Found
Ign:29 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-security/multiverse Translation-en
Ign:36 http://ftp.debian.org/debian wheezy-backports InRelease           
Get:37 http://ftp.debian.org/debian jessie-backports InRelease [166 kB]  
Ign:15 http://ppa.launchpad.net/libreoffice/libreoffice-4-4/ubuntu xenial/main all Packages
Ign:30 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-security/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:17 http://ppa.launchpad.net/libreoffice/libreoffice-4-4/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en_US
Ign:31 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-security/multiverse DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:18 http://ppa.launchpad.net/libreoffice/libreoffice-4-4/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en
Ign:32 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-security/main amd64 Packages    
Ign:37 http://ftp.debian.org/debian jessie-backports InRelease                 
Ign:20 http://ppa.launchpad.net/libreoffice/libreoffice-4-4/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:22 http://ppa.launchpad.net/libreoffice/libreoffice-4-4/ubuntu xenial/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:33 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-security/main i386 Packages     
Ign:16 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-security/main all Packages      
Ign:19 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-security/main Translation-en_US 
Ign:21 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-security/main Translation-en    
Ign:23 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-security/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:24 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-security/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:34 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-security/multiverse amd64 Packages
Ign:35 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-security/multiverse i386 Packages
Ign:27 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-security/multiverse all Packages
Ign:28 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-security/multiverse Translation-en_US
Ign:29 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-security/multiverse Translation-en
Ign:30 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-security/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:31 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-security/multiverse DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:32 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-security/main amd64 Packages    
Ign:33 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-security/main i386 Packages     
Ign:16 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-security/main all Packages      
Ign:19 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-security/main Translation-en_US 
Ign:21 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-security/main Translation-en    
Ign:23 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-security/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:24 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-security/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:34 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-security/multiverse amd64 Packages
Ign:35 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-security/multiverse i386 Packages
Ign:27 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-security/multiverse all Packages
Ign:28 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-security/multiverse Translation-en_US
Ign:29 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-security/multiverse Translation-en
Ign:30 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-security/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:31 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-security/multiverse DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:32 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-security/main amd64 Packages    
Ign:33 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-security/main i386 Packages     
Ign:16 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-security/main all Packages      
Ign:19 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-security/main Translation-en_US 
Ign:21 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-security/main Translation-en    
Ign:23 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-security/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:24 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-security/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:34 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-security/multiverse amd64 Packages
Ign:35 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-security/multiverse i386 Packages
Ign:27 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-security/multiverse all Packages
Ign:28 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-security/multiverse Translation-en_US
Ign:29 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-security/multiverse Translation-en
Ign:30 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-security/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:31 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-security/multiverse DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:32 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-security/main amd64 Packages    
Ign:33 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-security/main i386 Packages     
Ign:16 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-security/main all Packages      
Ign:19 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-security/main Translation-en_US 
Ign:21 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-security/main Translation-en    
Ign:23 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-security/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:24 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-security/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:34 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-security/multiverse amd64 Packages
Ign:35 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-security/multiverse i386 Packages
Ign:27 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-security/multiverse all Packages
Ign:28 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-security/multiverse Translation-en_US
Ign:29 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-security/multiverse Translation-en
Ign:30 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-security/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:31 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-security/multiverse DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Err:32 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-security/main amd64 Packages    
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]
Err:33 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-security/main i386 Packages     
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]
Err:34 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-security/multiverse amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]
Err:35 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-security/multiverse i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]
Fetched 329 kB in 18s (18.0 kB/s)                                              
Reading package lists... Done
W: The repository 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-security Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/libreoffice/libreoffice-4-4/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: http://ftp.debian.org/debian wheezy-backports InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 8B48AD6246925553  NO_PUBKEY 7638D0442B90D010
W: The repository 'http://ftp.debian.org/debian wheezy-backports InRelease' is not signed.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: There is no public key available for the following key IDs:
8B48AD6246925553  NO_PUBKEY 7638D0442B90D010  
W: GPG error: http://ftp.debian.org/debian jessie-backports InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 8B48AD6246925553  NO_PUBKEY 7638D0442B90D010
W: The repository 'http://ftp.debian.org/debian jessie-backports InRelease' is not signed.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: There is no public key available for the following key IDs:
8B48AD6246925553  NO_PUBKEY 7638D0442B90D010  
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/libreoffice/libreoffice-4-4/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/libreoffice/libreoffice-4-4/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/lucid-security/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/lucid-security/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/lucid-security/multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/lucid-security/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: Try to run `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`

Comment: Have you installed anything via a non-standard ppa?

Comment: Have you installed something directly from a `.deb`?

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson tried ur command, and then tried to install librre office again but it didnt wor too

Comment: @Marc no. nothing but java and flash. and i think i don't have the program that install .deb packages

Comment: Can you run the command `sudo apt-get update` and show us the whole output by editing your question.

Comment: `sudo apt install -f` will try to fix problems with the installation.

Comment: I'd be curious to see the output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list` and  `dir /etc/apt/sources.list.d` . . .  that would show the repositories you're trying to use.

Comment: How did you upgrade?  With `sudo do-release-upgrade`?  And what did you have in the first place?  You have Debian source repos on there which may explain how your system is broken.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson done

Comment: @Marc Done .   sorry for the late reply . I actually dobt that migt be the problem but i dont know how to be sure

Comment: @ThomasW. I didnt upgrade, I have installed a new version of ubuntu

Comment: We need to know what you did after installing.  Because you have a lot of broken bits of the package manager with the repos you have enabled and such, and that probably traces back to something you did after installation.

Comment: @ThomasW. it happened before i need to do anything. the first thing i tried to install using apt command is flash player. then when i couldn't do so i have changed from the local repositories to the global ones. anyway, i guess most of the failure statements from the repositories i was trying to add manually. so i am not very alerted about them

Comment: and that makes me wonder if i want to install the required packages for the LibreOffice,as example, how would i do that ?

Answer (score 1):

One of the core problems in your setup is you are mixing Debian and Ubuntu repositories, as well as mixing in Lucid repositories.  How this happened in your setup, I do not know because this is not able to be replicated on ANY setup I have ever worked with (including upgrade setups).

Here's some things you ***must remove*** from your sources.  Lucid Security is dead, and has been for an eon, and including Debian repos in Ubuntu will break things:

```
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-security main multiverse
deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian wheezy-backports main
deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian jessie-backports main
```

These three are at the bottom of your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file.

#### Never mix Debian and Ubuntu repositories together on the same system.  *EVER.*

This is what ***breaks installations majorly***.  Start by removing the repositories I specified, and using `sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get install -f` again, and see if the issues of unmet dependencies still happen.

Comment: removed them but no change. still getting unmet dependencies when i am trying ti install libre office

Answer (score 0):

Taking you literally - "after installing a new Ubuntu version (16.04", -  before trying to install anything with apt you must refresh your sources, ie.

`sudo apt update`

(in 16.04 one can just use apt rather than apt-get, it a bit more full featured

Comment: I did. and alot more. alooooot more